# Parsing a WSDL file like XML?

Tags: ios, xml, wsdl

I'm receiving a file from a server, but instead of being an xml file it is a wsdl file with the same exact text that would be in an xml file. Since the content is the exact same can I parse it as if it were an xml file? Or do I need to convert it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

[WSDL](http://www.w3schools.com/wsdl/wsdl_intro.asp) is in fact a XML to describe and locate web services.  It is not the content itself. Even though technically you can parse it, you should expect a XML file from server.